NRA/RA Test and FICA exemption
I was on F-1 from 2018-08 to 2020-05 in the US, but I stayed in my home country from 2020-05 to 2022-09 and I came back to the US from 2022-09 till now. I am on F-1 all the time, and technically 2024 is my 6th year in the US (2018, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2023 2024), so am I considered NRA or RA? Am I eligible for FICA exemption?

The FICA exemption based on F1 status and an exempt job no longer applies even if you're a non-resident, since 2024 is your sixth calendar year in status. As to the residency status, check the substantial presence test and count days. Only the days in F1 status during 2018-2023 are exempt.
Note that there's a different FICA exemption for students, that may apply even to residents, under the IRC Sec. 3121(b)(10)

Just to confirm, I am considered to be RA in the year of 2024 even with that gap between 2020-2022?

you get 5 calendar years, and if you were in F1 status any time during the year - that year counts. So you have 2018, 2019, 2020, 2022, 2023 - that's 5 years.

Thank you so much!
